# Having issues wrapping checkbox content within a an ItemsControl without using a TextBlock with wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, checkbox, itemscontrol

I am new to C# and have been running into some issues. I am trying to add checkboxes to an ItemsControl, and read off the caption of the checkbox if it is checked. The checkbox caption must be wrapped within the Items Control, as the captions can get very long. The code below adds items to my ItemsControl, but the text is not wrapped:

```
        var items = new ObservableCollection<CheckBox>();
        items.Add(new CheckBox() { Content = "Long text", IsChecked = false }); 
        itemControl.ItemsSource = items;
```

Now, if I want to wrap the text, I can do the following:

```
        var items = new ObservableCollection<CheckBox>();
        items.Add(new CheckBox() { Content = {Text = "Long text", TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWithOverflow}, IsChecked = false }); 
        itemControl.ItemsSource = items;
```

The problem with this is that I cannot seem to get the caption of the checkbox. When trying to reference the content, for example:

```
        foreach (CheckBox item in listBox.Items)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked == true)
                Console.WriteLine(item.Content);
        }
```

The console will only output that the content is a TextBlock, it shows `System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock`.

I have tried numerous way to try to have both the wrapping, and the caption able to be read. All come up short, sadly. I attempted to see if I could access the Content method to get the string from the textblock, but no dice, `item.Content.Textblock` can not be accessed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set an [ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @ChrisW. I have an item template, yes. But you can't set word wrapping for checkboxes this way, I think. `TextWrapping` is not a member for CheckBoxes. Unless there is another way to do this.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood. If you're talking about setting the content of Checkbox to wrap (as opposed to just using a stackpanel with a checbox/textblock respectively) what you can do is edit a checkbox style template, replace the ContentPresenter with a TextBlock with a TemplateBinding to Content with TextWrapping set and you're done. Only caveat though is it would no longer support embedded objects or anything but text as content.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks for the answer. But you might need to dumb it down for me. I am still trying to get a grasp on this language. I found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684355/wpf-checkbox-style-change) on what a control template is, and I am trying to add a new control to the XAML. This template needs to be modified to have a TextBlock, and the TextBlock must be set to wrap in the ItemTemplate? That should do the trick?

Comment: Yea for your instance, if you want a custom checkbox, you can right click a checkbox -> Edit Template -> Edit A Copy and plop a copy of the template either on your control or in a resource dictionary or something. Then you'll just slap in a `<TextBlock Text={TemplateBinding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>` in place of the ContentPresenter, I'd have to go look at a default but I think it's in a grid anyway in the template to separate the visual for the checkbox and the Contentpresenter, in which case your wrapping should get invoked anytime it runs out of room.

Comment: `CheckBox` is a `ContentControl`, so it will display your item however you like, using whatever `DataTemplate` you specify. Without a good [mcve] it's impossible to fully understand your scenario, but IMHO you should never have `ObservableCollection<CheckBox>`; instead, you should have `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`, define a `DataTemplate` for that model (in which you have the template declared to do wrapping the way you want) and just bind the `CheckBox.Content` to the item (i.e. `Content={Binding}`).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisW., I got it to work. If you leave an answer I can mark it as the correct solution!

Comment: No worries man, I didn't answer it, just gave a path to an option, post your own and mark it as answer and I'll upvote ya. :)